# SSCLI for .Net Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, sscli

Is there a SSCLI equivalent for .Net Framework 3.5?
Something that can be debugged and stepped through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 (and especially VS2008 SP1) you should enable the ".NET Framework source stepping" debugger option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a patch for the source code of sscli and then you can build through VS 2008.